# Unity - Button not accessible for click event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ui-toolkit

Using UI Builder, I created a card that displays a value and has a button that needs to be pressed. In my scene, the order of hierarchy is Canvas > Button > Quad > UI document. The button turns the Quad on and off. It is currently disabled. Right now, I'm concentrating on pressing the UI document button. Here, I'm having some problems. Cant really figure out why.

This is my UXML logic:

```
<ui:UXML xmlns:ui="UnityEngine.UIElements" xmlns:uie="UnityEditor.UIElements" editor-extension-mode="False">
    <Style src="project://database/Assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.uss?fileID=7433441132597879392&amp;guid=d125947a27bfde547b59765e8fdd13cd&amp;type=3#stylesheet" />
    <ui:VisualElement name="cardOneContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 600px; border-top-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; border-top-right-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0; width: 100%;">
        <ui:VisualElement name="headerContainer" class="header-text" style="height: 20%; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; background-color: rgb(45, 85, 255);">
            <ui:Label text="ParameterOne" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="headerText" class="value-text" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; color: rgb(255, 235, 235);" />
        </ui:VisualElement>
        <ui:VisualElement name="dataContainer" style="height: 80%;">
            <ui:VisualElement name="valueContainer" style="height: 70%; justify-content: space-around;">
                <ui:VisualElement name="tempContainer" style="height: 30%; flex-direction: row;">
                    <ui:Label text="Temp" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="tempHeader" style="height: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -unity-text-align: middle-center; font-size: 50px; width: 50%; -unity-font-style: bold;" />
                    <ui:Label text="N/A" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="tempValue" style="height: 100%; -unity-text-align: middle-center; font-size: 100px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 50%; -unity-font-style: bold;" />
                </ui:VisualElement>
                <ui:VisualElement name="capContainer" style="height: 30%; flex-direction: row;">
                    <ui:Label text="Capacity" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="capHeader" style="height: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -unity-text-align: middle-center; font-size: 50px; width: 50%; -unity-font-style: bold;" />
                    <ui:Label text="N/A" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="capValue" style="height: 100%; -unity-text-align: middle-center; font-size: 100px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 50%; -unity-font-style: bold;" />
                </ui:VisualElement>
            </ui:VisualElement>
            <ui:VisualElement name="buttonContainer" style="height: 30%; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                <ui:Button text="ADD" display-tooltip-when-elided="true" name="addMedia" class="add-button" />
            </ui:VisualElement>
        </ui:VisualElement>
        <ui:VisualElement name="bottomContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; opacity: 1;">
            <ui:VisualElement name="scrim" style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);" />
            <ui:VisualElement name="bottomSheet" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 50%; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255); border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;" />
        </ui:VisualElement>
    </ui:VisualElement>
</ui:UXML>
```

This is the script I have attached to the UI document:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class CardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private VisualElement _bottomContainer;

    private Button _addButton;

    void Start()
    {
        var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;

        _bottomContainer = root.Q<VisualElement>("bottomContainer");

        _addButton = root.Q<Button>("addMedia");

        _bottomContainer.style.display = DisplayStyle.None;
        
        if(_addButton != null){
        Debug.Log("Button detected!");
        _addButton.RegisterCallback<ClickEvent>(addButtonClicked); 
        }      
    }

    private void addButtonClicked(ClickEvent evt)
    {   
        Debug.Log("Button clicked!");
        _bottomContainer.style.display = DisplayStyle.Flex;
    }

}
```

I see 'Button detected' log in the console, that means the button is accessed in the script.  however, the click is not being triggered for some reason.

Comment: call me old fashioned, but this is is why i like the older unity UI, it had objects you wanted an object you found it like any other, you wanted to add a click event, you added it, it didnt give you this kinda problem..  Ive never had my UI be the reason my game was losing fps.

Answer (score 0):

Code `_addButton.clickable.clicked += () => { /* Your code */ };` works fine.

Comment: No, its not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).